# How to tell if frequency or the radian frequency

Tags: power, homework

****The question is as shown below:****

[image]

My question is about Problem 7.2 d) The frequency at which maximum current occurs in problem 7.2 c) is as shown in the figure below:

[image]

However, the answer of the book is

[image]

My question is how do I know if he is asking for the frequency or the radian frequency (i.e. angular frequency).

Comment: Should that even matter? If you are asked to calculate speed, you can calculate at m/s, kmph, miles/hour etc. They are just units.

Comment: As long as you state the units it shouldn't matter.

Comment: Usually, when people say just "frequency", they refer to cyclic frequency (measured in hertz). // Anyways, if this is a homework, to try to avoid problems with the professor I'd calculate both the cyclic frequency and the angular frequency. If it's just you practicing, I'd calculate only one, unless I'm particularly interested in both.

Comment: State both if your prof is picky. But if he has some common sense he will accept either. As long as you specify the units of course.